# How to rebase with merges?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, repository, rebase

Let's say I have a mix of commits and merges on top of master in my clone. Now I want to push it somewhere, but I get a message that my changes cannot be fast-forwarded.

If I had only commits, I'd just do a `pull --rebase`, `push` and I'd have it done. But if I have merges in the way, pulling with rebase would destroy them. How do I deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you will want to do a `git fetch`. Once you have pulled in the remote branch tip, manually rebase/merge/cherry-pick your local work on top of it. Once you have arranged it the way you want, push your changes back to the remote.

[Here](http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/) is some great reasoning on why you would want to use fetch instead of pull.

Comment: I'd rather not do it manually. What I'm after is one command that would "just put my changes on top of upstream master". `pull --rebase` does that already, but it destroys some information in the process.

Comment: Do you need to do a FF merge?  You could use the default `git pull` and hope the merge goes as planned.

Comment: I don't want another merge point - that gets too confusing after a while. I just want to move my changes on top of master.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with this situation to offer you more help, but manually setting things up may be the only way.  Else you can change your workflow so that that this situation can be dealt with easier.

Answer (score 0):

To rebase and preserve merges, you can specify the `--preserve-merges` option to the rebase command. Depending on how easily each commit applies as a patch, this may or may not be easy to do.

I would fetch changes first, then inspect and take action.